# A loop with figures and plots

Tags: python, pandas, loops, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to do a loop where each `i` has a figure with two plots. The difference between the plots are given by a binary column. For example:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'vehicle': ['car', 'truck', 'bus', 'car', 'bus' ], 
                   'sex': ['male','male','male','female','female'],
                   'income': ['60000', '50000', '65000', '70000', '60000'],
                   'age': [31,25,67,90,18],
                   'crash' : [1,0,0,0,1]
})
```

Each figure has to have two graphs and it shows the relationship between all the variables and the `crash` column for two cases `(crash=1 and crash=0)` for each column. Here is my code, but it's still not working:

```
for i in train.columns:
    i_1 = train[i][train["crash"] == 1]
    i_0 = train[i][train["crash"] == 0]

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 10)) 
    fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1,2,2)
    ax1.plot(train[i], i_1)
    ax2.plot(train[i], i_0)
    plt.show()
```

So, figure 1 has two graphs. Graph 1 is the `count` of vehicles with `crash=1` and graph 2 is the `count` of vehicles with `crash=0`. The figure 2, graph 1 is the `count` of sex with `crash=1` and graph 2 is the `count` of sex with `crash=0`. And so on.. for a total (in this case) of 4 figures.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem? "it's not working" is not a problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an aggregating to get metrics for count.

The following example should get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

train = pd.DataFrame({'vehicle': ['car', 'truck', 'bus', 'car', 'bus' ], 
                   'sex': ['male','male','male','female','female'],
                   'income': ['60000', '50000', '65000', '70000', '60000'],
                   'age': [31,25,67,90,18],
                   'crash' : [1,0,0,0,1]
})

for i in train.columns:
    if i == 'crash':
        continue

    table = pd.pivot_table(train[[i, 'crash']], index=[i], aggfunc=np.sum)
    table.plot.bar()
```